# XSLT - get nodes one by one

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml like this,

```
<doc>
    <data/>
    <books>
        <name>abc</name>
        <name>def</name>
    </books>
    <link>
        <booklink>abc.com</booklink>
        <booklink>def.com</booklink>
    </link>
</doc>
```

I need to transfer this using xslt to a different structure,

expected output:

```
<doc>
    <link ref="abc.com">abc</link>
    <link ref="def.com">def</link>
    <books>
        <name>abc</name>
        <name>def</name>
    </books>
    <link>
        <booklink>abc.com</booklink>
        <booklink>def.com</booklink>
    </link>
</doc>
```

I have written following xslt for do this,

Note: `<booklink>` can be less that number of `<name>`. example here it can be  `<booklink>` available. If so, only first `<name>` should get the link. if no `<booklink>` available, no link should be appear in `<name>`. otherwise `<booklink>` should be add in document order (position).

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <link ref="{xyz:get-booklink(.)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="xyz:get-book-name(.)"/>
        </link>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:function name="xyz:get-book-name">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="$node/(/)/doc/books/name"/>
    </xsl:function>


    <xsl:function name="xyz:get-booklink">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="$node/(/)/doc/link/booklink"/>
    </xsl:function>
```

But my current output is,

```
<doc>
    <link ref="abc.com def.com">abc def</link>
    <books>
        <booklink>abc</name>
        <name>def</name>
    </books>
    <link>
        <booklink>abc.com</booklink>
        <booklink>def.com</booklink>
    </link>
</doc>
```

So i'm unable to get booklink and name one by one.. any suggestion how can i do this?

Comment: What links a book to a link? Is it just the position in the input XML?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, yes..t just the position.. if only one link available only first book should get the like.. if no link available, books should not get the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:for-each select="/doc/link/booklink">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
        <link ref="{.}">
            <xsl:value-of select="/doc/books/name[$i]"/>
        </link>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```